# Oracle SQL - Produce multiple different aggregations using analytic functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, window-functions

I have a table that I want to aggregate by two different columns, `prop1` and `prop2`.

```
 id | prop1 | prop2 | val
--------------------------
 1  | A     | B     | 10
 2  | A     | A     | 15
 3  | B     | B     | 20
 4  | B     | A     | 30
```

The desired output is:

```
 prop_name | prop_val | sum_val
--------------------------------
 prop1     | A        | 25
 prop1     | B        | 50
 prop2     | A        | 45
 prop2     | B        | 30
```

I know I can do this using a union (see below), but is there a better way using the analytic functions?

```
with 
  test_data as (
      select 1 as id, 'A' as prop1, 'B' as prop2, 10 as val from dual union all
      select 2 as id, 'A' as prop1, 'A' as prop2, 15 as val from dual union all
      select 3 as id, 'B' as prop1, 'B' as prop2, 20 as val from dual union all
      select 4 as id, 'B' as prop1, 'A' as prop2, 30 as val from dual
  )
select
   'prop1' as prop_name
  , prop1 as prop_val
  , sum(val)  as sum_val
from test_data
group by 'prop1', prop1

union all

select
  'prop2' as prop_name
  , prop2 as prop_val
  , sum(val)  as sum_val
from test_data
group by 'prop2', prop2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with grouping sets:

```
select prop1, prop2, sum(val)
from test_data
group by grouping sets ((prop1), (prop2))
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/5647) is your example.

Getting your exact output requires a bit more work.

```
select (case when prop1 is null then 'prop2' else 'prop1' end) as prop_name,
       coalesce(prop1, prop2) as prop,
       sum(value)
from test_data
group by grouping sets ((prop1), (prop2));
```

This assumes that the first two columns do not contain `NULL` values.  The better way to express the logic is using `GROUPING_ID` or `GROUP_ID()`, but I think the logic is easier to follow with `COALESCE()`.